# Error regarding static interface methods on my android project

Tags: android, static, butterknife

I am making a project of connecting to the star wars api, getting json object replies and presenting them on my View through recycleView (in short). However i am getting erros on build project through my gradle file (here in its entirety) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
    // language features (either in its source code or
    // through dependencies).
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.juangm.bottomnavigationmvp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.3.2'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'
}
```

The error i am getting : **Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void butterknife.Unbinder.lambda$static$0()
Stack trace:
**

As you can see, i have already added the compile options for JAVA.version 1_8 on the gradle, but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Do update the Biutterknife version to latest as below and sync. Had observed the butterknife

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

Android Studio should be updated to ver 4.0 to make use of Java 8 Desugaring as per Android docs. [Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)